# Can I make a particle system with fluid physics influence a dynamic rigidbody?

Tags: particles, physics, rigidbody

I am currently trying to make a simulation of a hydroelectric dam for a school project. I can currently get the particle system to populate the particles, and make them behave in a fluid-like manner when colliding with objects that aren't moving. I cannot seem to make the particles influence a cube with a dynamic rigidbody though. I'm still pretty new to blender, and this is the first time I have even tried making something with physics, so I have no idea what settings I need to toggle or plugins I need to install to make this work. If anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated. Preferably in terms someone with very little physics knowledge can understand.

Comment: The physics behavior you are looking for is called *2-way coupling* (meaning fluid influences rigid body and rigid body influences fluid). There are probably other and simpler methods (for example 1-way coupling). Hope it helps you somehow.

Comment: And, the answer to can you do 2-way coupling is, "No."  But are you actually interested in 2-way coupling?  It is *technically* possible to get a particle system to interact with a rigid body system, one-way, from particle->rigid body (rigid body->particle is trivial IIRC, just give the rigid body a collision modifier.)  My experiments to make it work are rather tricky, hacky, a pain in the butt.  Do you want a 1-way, PITB solution?

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new, can you explain what those acronyms mean? All I really want is for a turbine to turn when particles collide with it's blades. From what I can gather, having the turbine be stationary can be achieved with rigidbody constraints, but what would 1-way coupling look like? Does that mean that the rigidbody is forced like the particles have infinite mass since the particles can influence the rigidbody but particles cannot be influenced by the rigidbody?

Comment: The acronym I used was PITB, "pain in the butt."  Two-way would be if you wanted the turbine to turn with the particles *and* slow the particles as they collided with it; one-way would be if you only needed the particles to turn the turbine.  Could we literally make collision from particles turn the turbine?  No.  Anything we did would be a hack.  But we could link the turbine rate to the particle flow rate, for example.  Still, the best solution here is to hand keyframe.  Setting up a hack will take a long time.  Keyframing a few good-enough values will take a short time.

Comment: So essentially just disabling the dynamic property of the rigidbody and animating the turbine rotating by hand in the relevant parts of the simulation is the way to go here? 1-way coupling from particles influencing a rigidbody is too difficult/tedious to accomplish in a reasonable timeframe?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.  If you wanted, you could keep it dynamic and animate something to which it was constrained-- but that's six of one, a half-dozen of the other.  Getting particles to drive the rotation is more difficult than just making the rotation.

Comment: Oh pardon, "IIRC" is "if I remember correctly": I'm pretty sure, but I wouldn't wager my family's lives on it.